# How do I get SciPy to return x values from y maxima?

Tags: python, scipy

I am writing a script to plot a graph from a csv ('column A' is 'x', 'column B' is 'y') and return the 'x' values at one or more 'y'  maxima.

I am currently using the scipy find_peaks function to find the maxima but I'm a bit stuck as to how I can then return the 'x' values. Currently I can output the array of the 'y' value positions in my input file but then I'm stuck. I'm pretty new to this so sorry if I've gone about this the wrong way!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from scipy.signal import find_peaks

x = []
y = []

with open('data.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(x,y, marker=' ')

peaks = find_peaks(y, height=100,)
print(peaks)
```

I'm running this in Spyder, the image below (linked) has the output. The key part is this:

```
(array([14, 17, 30], dtype=int64), {'peak_heights': array([1000.,  700.,  300.])})
```

I would ideally like to use the numbers in the first array to find the 'x' values from the csv file. Is this possible?

[image: Output image]

Comment: if the first array returned is the position, then you can use those positions with your x array: `numpy.array(x)[peaks[0]`

Comment: Thanks @PaulH that is exactly what i needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @PaulH achieves what I wanted to do. Including his solution from the comments above I now have this as the script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import numpy

x = []
y = []

with open('data.csv','r') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.plot(x,y, marker=' ')

peaks = find_peaks(y, height=100,)

### This section is from @PaulH ###

list = numpy.array(x)[peaks[0]]
print(list)

###################################
```

The output now includes this line:

```
[-1.5  -0.75  2.5 ]
```

Which includes the 'x' values for the three maxima in my data set.

Thanks!